# SQL Server Hash joins and nested loops

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-execution-plan

I develop reports on existing databases (SQL2008 - SQL2012) where I need to collect data in many different ways.

A typical query can look like

```
WITH ThisYearData AS (
    SELECT ...
)
,LastYearData AS (
    SELECT ...
)
,BudgetData AS (
    SELECT ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM SomeDateTable
     LEFT JOIN ThisYearData
         ON ...
     LEFT JOIN BudgetData
     ...
```

Sometimes the CTEs are dependent on each other and a typical query involves 5-10 of them.

The problem is that similar queries can take anything from a second to 5 minutes to run on a small set of data.

The main reason for slow performance is that SQL Server uses nested loops instead of hash joins. In some cases I can just put in a `HASH JOIN` in the right place to make the query 100 times faster. In other cases I convert one or more of the CTEs to a table variable instead.

I know the the reason for selecting nested loops over hash joins is based on the estimated number of rows which is based on statistics.
In my cases I don't have access to the database schema so I can't add index or statistics but I can ensure that existing statistics is updated (and auto create/update statistics is enabled).

To find the nested loop(s) causing the slowdown I do like this:

1. Find nodes with a high number of rows and executions
2. Follow the path upwards until I find the right nested loop
3. Find out which join is causing the nested loop and force it to a `hash join`

([SQL Sentry explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/) makes this so much easier)

My questions are:

1. Do I do something fundamentally wrong which causes SQL Server to almost always underestimate number of rows (single digit estimated and actual in thousands is common)
2. The execution plan usually show some unrelated table scan with a high percentage which is not very helpful. What is the percentage in the execution plan based on? Can I change it to be more helpful in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Using WITH is a sure performance penalty, at least on SQL Server in my experience. Write your queries without the WITH construct and see if you get a performance improvement (my money is on: YES).

If even that does't work, construct what you would otherwise select from a CTE or derived table, in a temporary table. A table variable is only best if the number of rows is really small (ie 10 or less). Temporary tables at least from my experience offer best performance if you notice that your query with CTE/derived table is too slow.

Comment: I have not seen any performance problems with CTEs or table variables. If I just force `HASH JOIN` the performance is acceptable (and readability/maintainability of CTEs over other solutions is very valuable)

Comment: @adrianm I can only speak from experience, and that is from SQL 2005 and 2008. Any sufficiently complex query running on large data sets, runs faster if you rewrite it without WITH by using temporary tables. Of course if your query runs in seconds, it's no use optimizing it. If it runs for hours then certainly. That's not theory, it's something I've learned from practice. I can't speak for other versions, or RDMS's. And readability/maintainability really doesn't suffer IMO, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Just a pointer for you to look into the cause of bad performance using CTE's/derived tables: look into CTE materialization, and why that is necessary in some cases. CTE's are not materialized and in some cases are rebuilt every time it is accessed. They also don't have indices or statistics. Temporary tables are materialized by design, and can have indices/statistics. What you choose to construct your query, should depend on complexity and number of rows. A simple query dealing with little rows needs no optimization. Massively complex queries over a lot of rows most likely will if you use WITH

Comment: At least in tests I've done, using table variables is slower than using temporary tables. The main issue is that table variables do not have statistics, while temporary tables do. Table variables can only have a primary key (or unique constraint), while temporary tables can have an arbitrary number of indices. You can look up comparisons online... rule of thumb: use table variables for UDF returns, temporary tables for temp storage/temp data manipulation, particularly with large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

> The execution plan usually show some unrelated table scan with a high
>   percentage which is not very helpful. What is the percentage in the
>   execution plan based on? Can I change it to be more helpful in my
>   scenario?

The problem with adding hint 'hash join' is that it causes an implicit 'force order' of all the other joins too.

From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815(v=sql.105).aspx :

> Remarks
>
> Join hints are specified in the FROM clause of a query. Join hints
>   enforce a join strategy between two tables. If a join hint is
>   specified for any two tables, the query optimizer automatically
>   enforces the join order for all joined tables in the query, based on
>   the position of the ON keywords.

I think you should make a copy of the database and add statistics to try to improve the performance in a test environment and see what happens. If it helps then you can talk with a decision maker or you can create a datawarehouse.